# Using IOC To Configure Unit and Integration Tests

Tags: unit-testing, inversion-of-control, integration-testing, mstest

I have a unit test project which uses Ninject to mock the database repositories. I would like to use these same tests as integration tests and use Ninject to bind my real database repositories back into their respective implementations so as to test/stress the application into the DB.

Is there a way to do this with Visual Studio 2012 or is there another test framework, other than MSTest, which allows for this type of configuration?

I would really hate to rewrite/copy these unit tests into an integration test project but I suspect I could copy the files in as links and have a single test file compiled into two projects (Unit and Integration).

Thanks
Todd

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements sound really odd to me. The difference between a unit test and an integration test is much bigger than just connecting to a database or not. An integration test either has a much bigger scope, or tests if components communicate correctly. When you write a unit test, the scope of such a unit is normally small (one class/component with all dependencies mocked out), which means there is no need for using a DI container.

Let me put it differently. When the tests are exactly the same, why are you interested to do the same test with and without the database. Just leave the database in and just test that. Besides these tests, you can add 'real' unit tests, that have a much smaller scope.

Comment: Suppose I have a Service which implements IService which has a dependency on IServiceRepository which is implemented by SqlServiceRepository and it hits a SQL DB. I want to run unit tests which target IService so I create a MockServiceRepository which implements IServiceRepository and use DI to switch out the SQL repository for the Mock repository which just uses in-memory collections. This works perfectly locally and works on my build server as well. Now I want to test the SqlRepository using the same Unit tests but instead of using the Mock Repository I want to use the SQL Repository.

Comment: You are trying to reuse the same test to test something completely different. Write a different test to test the SqlRepository in isolation. This way the test is much more focussed and much more trustworthy.

Comment: Agreed that would work however then I do not get an end to end test which is what I was calling an integration test.

Comment: An end-to-end test is an acceptance test. This is something you should let users do. Perhaps even automate this using FitNesse. If you have enough integration tests and unit tests, you will be pretty sure the system works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

With Nunit you can do this with TestCase,

say you need to use the unit and unit/integration test using CustomerRepository and OrderRepository,

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestCustomerRepository
{
    IKernel _unit;
    Ikernel _integration;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
       //setup both kernels
    }

    [TestCase("Unit")]
    [TestCase("Integration")]
    public void DoTest(String type)
    {
        var custRepo = GetRepo<ICustomerRepository>(type);
        var orderRepo = GetRepo<IOrderRepository>(type);
        //do the test here
    }

    protected T GetRepo<T>(String type)
    {
        if (type.Equals("Unit"))
        {
            return _unit.Get<T>();
        }
        return _integration.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

This is the basic idea.